# How can I use functions in another program

Tags: module

I want to create a simulation program, for BUS related simulations.

These simulations use lot of calculations, and methods, and there are more and more.

First I want to write the Core of the program, which can use separately coded and compiled program blocks. What kind of programming technology is good for this?

For example: I want to send a CAN frame with checksum calculation. In the core program I choose from a directory that which checksum calculation is good for me.

Comment: Maybe like, DLLs?

Comment: libs(Linux) or DLL(win) is what you need . all the code that you need to shear be in be lib and the program will include and link to your libs

Comment: Please take a look at [this link](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/buildlib.html) to build your own library in C (or C++). So you check your application for common functions and export them into a library. You can use this library in all your applications after that.

Comment: Any simulation, that runs is real-time will have a program look to keep a time-step that drives the remainder of the computations. You then add additional computation blocks to your program loop. [Dewitter Game Loop](https://dewitters.com/dewitters-gameloop/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Before diving into the topic of making libs (static or even dynamic) check out the possibility to just separate into reusable code files and headers. I get the impression that this would be enough to provide the kind of reusability you seem to need.

Comment: A compiler is good for separately compiled program parts. This question is too vague / broad to be useful.

Comment: If you make an example of a program which has a part which you want to reuse later, you will probably get answers which change it according to different methods. Keep it extremely small and simple though, check out the concept described here: [mcve]. Ignore the part about demonstrating an error. Just follow the idea to make something small and buildable, even if it successfully does nothing or some silly little output, similar to HelloWorld.

Comment: Nice to see upvotes on what seems to be a first question. Have a look at the [tour] to serve as a good-luck charm for your future participation here at StackOverflow. And welcome to the community.